# The current Windows User is in the Administration group (vb 2k13)?

Tags: vb.net, admin

I need to check if the current Logon Windows account is an Administrator of the PC.

```
If My.User.IsInRole(ApplicationServices.BuiltInRole.Administrator) Then
    'Is Admin
Else
    'Isn't Admin
End If
```

This code work fine but if i lunch the code with RUN AS "another account" the code dont do the right job becouse take the account that lunch the code not the Windows account that is logged in.

With this code i can see the current Windows User logged in:

```
Dim Coll As ManagementObjectCollection
Dim LogonName As String
Dim GetName As New ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT UserName FROM Win32_ComputerSystem")
Coll = GetName.[Get]()
LogonName = DirectCast(Coll.Cast(Of ManagementBaseObject)().First()("UserName"), String)
Dim CleanName() As String = Split(LogonName, "\")
```

So in the string LogonName i'll have the Windows user name account that is logged in but how can i check if is an Administrator?

Comment: The whole idea of the 'Run as' option is to be able to use permissions your normal user account doesn't have...

Comment: the Win32_Group class has the user groups, the Win32_UserAccount class has the accounts and the Win32_GroupUser class links them. You should be able to work it out from there

Comment: I know the current user logon but i dont know how check if is an Administrator of pc (I have the current user name in a string).

Answer (score 1):

Just Try this

```
 Public Function isAdmin() As Boolean
    Dim isAdmin1 As Boolean
    Dim CurrUser As WindowsIdentity
    'this will gets the currently logged User
    CurrUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
    '****************************************
    'this will checks the current user is  an administrative user
    Dim principal As New WindowsPrincipal(CurrUser)
    isAdmin = principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator)
    Return isAdmin
 End Function
```

---

Created On [visual-studio-2008](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2008) ([.net-3.5](/questions/tagged/.net-3.5))

Comment: Don't work becouse CurrUser = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent() give the account that run the application not the real current windows user that is log in.

Comment: whats the ouptut that you are getting for `isAdmin` in different `user accounts` ?

Comment: and include `Dim strUsrName As String = CurrUser.Name` and tell me what you get in `strUsrName` ??

Comment: With the account test(isn't an admin): strUsrName=test isAdmin1=false With the account test and RUS AS Admin(is an admin): strUsrName=Admin isAdmin1=true

Comment: This code return the Run As account so. Only the code that i linked in the question give me the right log in account but i have the account in the string LogonName and idk how check if is an admin from a string.